# Material UI React-Autosuggest Scrollbar not working on selecting options arrow keys

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autosuggest

I am using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) and designed a React Auto Suggest component. 
Please go to stackblitz example from below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/autosuggest-scrollbar-issue

To reproduce the issue type "a" in the input, after options are loaded **go to the last option from the keyboard's arrow key. option is highlighted but scrollbar does not move.**

Unfortunately, I am not able to find anything related to scrolling the container. Any leads please..